# backbone request json from backend service (cross domain)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to request the json from the backend service using backbone, I want to request the data and then parse it into the required client side structure, so I want to know why the following simple example does not make a call out to the backend service:

```
Book = Backbone.Model.extend({});
Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book,
        url: 'http://foobar.cloudapp.net/contents',
        parse: function (response) {
            return response;
        }
    });
function default_start_up() {
    var books = new Books();
    books.fetch();
};
```

Comment: I would provide a relative url for your collection: "/contents". Do you get any JS errors? How does your JSON look like?

Comment: this isn't local, it's cross domain...

Comment: So you will have to implement your own fetch or sync method. Backbone does not support crossdomain ajax requests out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this jquery plugin with success [cross domain ajax](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/)